# Class agnostic Mask R-CNN

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, semantic-segmentation

How can I use the implementation of https://github.com/fizyr/keras-maskrcnn to perform class-agnostic segmentation ?
Indeed, the original Mask R-CNN paper mentions that class agnostic segmentation leads to same performances as class-specific masks.
However, I am not sure how the authors actually perform this class-agnostic based segmentation and then classify each segments. Actually, I do not know how one can label class-agnostic masks since we need to filter the very high number of predicted masks by thresholding on the class probability (in short, we need label probability to threshold on label-agnostic masks...).

The reason why I need to go class-agnostic is that I have to deal with potential unseen classes in the training set.
Therefore, I would like to get the features that leads to this segmentation so as to cut-off the classification part and be able to deal with new classes by analysis over the features that leads to segmentation.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you find an easy way to do this?